# Can not use ENUM in template

Tags: go

in my code i defined an enum as below:

```golang
type flag int

const (
    Admin flag = iota + 1 // iota = 0
    Editer
    Superuser
    Viewer
)
```

The info is passed to the template, and I do a comparison like:

```html
        {{range $i, $v := .Flags}}
                {{if or (eq $v 1) (eq $v 3)}} 
                    <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder= {{$v}} required>
                {{else}}
                        <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder= {{$v}} disabled>
                {{end}}

        {{end}}
```

As seen here, the comparison is done with the equivalent int `eq $v 1`, what I like to do is something like `eq $v Admin` so I use the enum name instead of its value.

Can I do this?

Comment: You can't. Go identifiers are not available in templates, only what you pass.

Comment: The only way you can do that is to create a template function from each `flag` and then pass those functions to the `Funcs` method before parsing the template, only then would you be able to have expressions like `eq $v Admin` in your template.

Comment: @mkopriva thanks, but i can not create a func like `func Admin() int { return 1 }` as here will be having `Admin` redeclaration error as it already declared as int in the enum!

Comment: @HasanAYousef you can call the func anything, or even use anon func literal, what matters is the *key* you use in the template.FuncMap, then you can invoke the func by the key. https://play.golang.org/p/5um8BrE0k03

Comment: @mkopriva Thanks, can you post this as an answer so I accept it as a solution.

Comment: @HasanAYousef you can also declare a method on the flag type and use the [method value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_values) as the template function to make it more neat: https://play.golang.org/p/cd-ZofL9RHs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can register template functions with the [`Funcs`](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template@go1.17.2#Template.Funcs) method for each of your enums, given them the same name as the enum's constant has, and then invoke the function within the template by simply referencing them.

i.e. to be able to do `eq $v Admin` inside a template you can do the following:

```golang
type flag int

const (
    Admin flag = iota + 1 // iota = 0
    // ...
)

var funcMap = template.FuncMap{
    "Admin":  func() flag { return Admin },
    // ...
}

var file = `{{ $v := . }}
{{- if eq $v Admin }}is admin{{ else }}is not admin{{ end }}
`

func main() {
    t := template.Must(template.New("t").Funcs(funcMap).Parse(file))

    for _, v := range []interface{}{Admin, 1234} {
        if err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, v); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        fmt.Println("----------------")
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/70O7ebuYuNX

```
is admin
----------------
is not admin
----------------
```

---

You can also declare a method on the flag type and use the [method value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_values) as the template function to make it more neat:

```golang
type flag int

func (f flag) get() flag { return f }

const (
    Admin flag = iota + 1 // iota = 0
    Editor
)

var funcMap = template.FuncMap{
    "Admin":  Admin.get,
    "Editor": Editor.get,
    // ...
}

var file = `{{ $v := . }}
{{- if eq $v Admin }}is admin{{ else }}is not admin{{ end }}
{{ if eq $v Editor }}is editor{{ else }}is not editor{{ end }}
`

func main() {
    t := template.Must(template.New("t").Funcs(funcMap).Parse(file))

    for _, v := range []interface{}{Admin, Editor, 1234} {
        if err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, v); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        fmt.Println("----------------")
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/4JLsqxoHs8H

```
is admin
is not editor
----------------
is not admin
is editor
----------------
is not admin
is not editor
----------------
```